# handling a function for two Selectors, jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two dropdownlists in my view. i wrote a jquery code to handle the Change function for these two but its not working.

```
$('#ddlDepartment,#ddlgrade').on('change',function () {       
        var ddlDepartment = $('#ddlDepartment').val();
        var grade = $('#ddlgrade').value();
        $.ajax('/AdminPages/showStudents/' + ddlDepartment+'/'+grade).done(function (data) {
            $('#lstStudents').html(data);
        });
        $.ajax('/AdminPages/ShowTeahcers/' + ddlDepartment).done(function (data1) {
            $('#ddlteacher').html(data1);
        });
        $.ajax('/AdminPages/ShowCourses/' + ddlDepartment+'/'+grade).done(function (data2) {
            $('#ddlCourse').html(data2);
        });
    });
```

sorry for that . this is the error i get :

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (AddClassMembersMiniPage:106)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
    at HTMLSelectElement.elemData.handl
```

Comment: How it's not working? Errors in console?

Comment: Not working is not a defition of problem

Comment: What's not working? Any errors? Also, is "ShowTeahcers" a typo for "ShowTeachers"?

Comment: it doesn't send the required data to specified Controller.

Comment: You're not sending data through the AJAX calls, you're just asking for the pages.

Comment: when i only use one selector it works fine. but with two selectores, it does`nt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the "Developer Tools" console for errors. The code does not reach `$.ajax` calls because of the typo.

Change

`$('#ddlgrade').value();`

to

`$('#ddlgrade').val();`

Comment: @user5752702 - (seeing how you have not accepted a single answer to your questions) it is customary to click the "checkmark" sign to the left of the answer that solves your problem